# Quantum group notation

Tags: notation, terminology, quantum-groups

I was jumping into the deep end and reading a few papers and lectures on quantum groups. My knowledge on Lie algebras is a bit thin but I was just wondering the notation used in the starting of [this document](http://webpages.math.luc.edu/~ptingley/oldseminars/QuantumGroupsSpring2011/lecture1.pdf):

> One should have $U_\hbar(g) = U(g)[[\hbar]]$ as a vector space [...]

**My question is, is the $\hbar$ the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ I have been seeing in other papers, and what does the $U(g)[[\hbar]]$ mean precisely?** Usually I see the quantum group notated as $U_q(g)$, so the sudden change in notation concerned me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case $\hbar$ is just a parameter. Frequently, one also denotes $U_{\hbar}(g)$ as $U_q(g)$.

$U(g)[[\hbar]]$ denotes the space of formal power series over $U(g)$, i.e. if $f\in U(g)[[\hbar]]$, then $$f=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_n \hbar^n$$ with $a_n\in U(g)$ for every $n$. (Sometimes people reindex so that the sum is over $\mathbb{N}$ or some other countable set.)

Comment: The álgebra with a q and the one with HBar are not the same thing.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez In this case they end up being the same; the quote from the document linked in the question is about how $U(g)[[\hbar]]$ is not actually the same as $U_{\hbar}(g)$.

Comment: They are isomorphic if you complete the one with the q.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation for the one half of the notation. It does seem that there is a difference bbetween $\hbar$ and $q$, as they switch to the notation of $q$ at the end of the lecture notes, letting $q = \exp(\hbar)$. In any case I follow the lecture notes better now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Usually $\hbar$ is simply the [reduced Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) $h/(2\pi)$.

I have sadly no idea why it is featured such prominently in your context.